# Extract all links from a list of items from a website

Tags: python, web-scraping

I was trying to use Python to extract all mural links from this website: https://streetartcities.com/cities/losangeles/artworks. But my code does not work properly and gives me an empty output. I don't know if the website contains JavaScript or another programming language. Can anyone explain the question briefly and help me debug my code? Thank you!

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning) ## ignore the Deprecation warning message

s = HTMLSession()

def get_mural_links():
    url = 'https://streetartcities.com/cities/losangeles/artworks'
    links = []
    r = s.get(url)

    grid = r.html.find('div.p-5 div.grid.mt-4.grid-cols-2.md\:grid-cols-3.gap-3')
    for item in grid:
        links.append(item.find('a', first=True).attrs['href'])
    return links

print(get_mural_links())
```

Comment: [streetartcities.com/cities/losangeles/artworks/1](https://streetartcities.com/cities/losangeles/artworks/1) leads to nowhere. Are you sure that you got the URL correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element you are trying to find is added lazily to the site later on using JavaScript. That said, you need [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/). Selenium browses a page in a more humanly fashion than that of `requests`.

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


def get_mural_links():
  url = 'https://streetartcities.com/cities/losangeles/artworks'
  grid_selector = 'div.p-5 div.grid.mt-4.grid-cols-2.md\:grid-cols-3.gap-3'

  # Instantiate a driver instance.
  # This will be the medium for us to scrape the links.
  driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  
  # Go to the given page, then wait for two seconds.
  driver.get(url)
  time.sleep(2)
  
  # Find the grid and iterate over its children.
  grid = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, grid_selector)
  links = []
  
  for child in grid.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a'):
    links.append(child.get_attribute('href'))
  
  return links
```

Try it:

```
print(get_mural_links()[:10])

'''
[
  'https://streetartcities.com/cities/losangeles/markers/e406c20c-7774-4aad-841a-7c5e10ec707b',
  'https://streetartcities.com/cities/losangeles/markers/736dabb7-5d3b-4231-8c11-1c289b643125',
  'https://streetartcities.com/cities/losangeles/markers/906d66d7-60c6-4e0d-8afc-db5591f724ca',
  'https://streetartcities.com/cities/losangeles/markers/4ad5536b-7447-41d3-8f32-7c7835da9d75',
  'https://streetartcities.com/cities/losangeles/markers/94cfc0d9-cd03-44d3-97cf-90dadbaa3f1b',
  'https://streetartcities.com/cities/losangeles/markers/5597',
  'https://streetartcities.com/cities/losangeles/markers/11514',
  'https://streetartcities.com/cities/losangeles/markers/c13e8d5b-a066-4a35-8236-8a3446b82251',
  'https://streetartcities.com/cities/losangeles/markers/4923',
  'https://streetartcities.com/cities/losangeles/markers/11991'
]
'''
```